# Syntax error: can't assign value to operator while implementing k-nearest neighbour classifier

Tags: python, numpy, knn

*Edited to include full error stack

Forgive me if this is a silly question, i am a total noob.

I'm creating a k-nearest neighbor classifier in python using numpy. But when i try to run knn_classifier.predict() on CIFAR-10 images (reshaped into 1-D arrays), i get this error.

```
File "<ipython-input-9-9df7a1ae9044>", line 1
    y-pred = knn.predict(x_ts, k=5)
                                   ^
SyntaxError: can't assign to operator
```

This didn't happen when i hadn't included 'k'(method varibale in predict) in an earlier version of the classifier, so i'm assuming its related to 'k', but i can't figure out what i'm doing wrong.

This is what I wrote:

```
   class knn_classifier:
   
     def __init__(self):
   
       pass
   
     def train(self, x, y):
   
       self.xtr = x
       self.ytr = y
   
     def predict(self, x, k=1):
   
       num_images = x.shape[0]
       y_pred = np.zeros(num_images, dtype=self.ytr.dtype)
       for i in range(num_images):
         distance = np.sum(np.abs(self.xtr - x[i,:]), axis=1)
         lowest = np.argsort(distance)
         lowest = lowest[:k]
         lowest_k = list(self.ytr[lowest])
         y_pred[i] = np.argmax(np.bincount(lowest_k))
       return y_pred
```

Comment: Please include the full error stack.

Comment: your error shows line  which you don't have in your code in question. You should show also code which makes problem in your error message.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a typo. You wrote "y-pred" with a dash rather than an underscore, which Python interprets as the operation `y` minus `pred`.

Comment: Wow, can't believe I'm this dumb. Thanks!

Comment: Don't worry, it happens to the best of us!